# Can Arduino Morse Translator Serial signal be passed to Text to Speech program?

Tags: arduino

I have working code for Arduino Morse Code Translator. Blinks and beeps back whatever is written into the Serial Monitor and types it back into the Serial Monitor. What I'd like to add is code to also port the letters/punctuation that Arduino blinks back into a "Text to Speech" program I have (Simple TTS Reader). Is it possible?

```
 `//Sketch 5_05WORKS   Morse Interpreter including punctuation


int ledPin = 13;
int dotDelay = 250; //set the delay to a quarter second

char ch;
byte newch;  //transposed punctuation values

char* letters[] =                                                // Letters A-Z
                  {
                    ".-", "-...", "-.-.", "..", ".",                         
                     "..-.", "--.", "....", "..",
                     ".---", "-.-", ".-..", "--", "-.",                    
                     "---", ".--.", "--.-", ".-.",
                     "...", "-", "..-", "...-", ".--",                     
                     "-..-", "-.--", "--.."
                  };

char* numbers[] =                                              // numbers 0-9         
                  {
                    "-----", ".----", "..---", "...--", "....-",  
                    ".....", "-....", "--...", "---..", "----."
                  };             

char* punct[] =                                                // punctuation marks
                  {
                   ".-.-.-", "--..--", ".----.",  "..--..",       //  .  ,   '   ?    
                   "-.--.", "-.--.-", "-.-.--", "-.-.-.",        //  (  )   !   ;
                   "---...", ".-..-.", ".--.-.", "-....-",        //  :  "  @  -
                   "..--.-", ".-.-.", "...-..-", "-...-",         //  _  +  $  =
                   ".-..."                                        //  &





                    ".-.-.-", "--..--", "..--..", ".----.",          //  (punctuation marks) . , ? '
                       "-.-.--", "-.--.", "-.--.-", ".-...",            //    ! ( ) &
                       "---...", "-.-.-.", "-...-", ".-.-.",            //    : ; = +
                       "-....-", "..--.-", ".-..-.", "...-..-",          //     - _ " $
                       ".--.-."                                         //    @
                  }; 


void setup()                                                                
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("To send text to be displayed in Morse Code, type words above and press Send");
}

void loop()
{

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
      ch = Serial.read();                                        //read a single letter

      if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')                              // is it lower case letter?
   {
      flashSequence(letters [ch - 'a']);
   }
  else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')                           // is it a capital letter?
   {
      flashSequence(letters [ch - 'A']);
   }
  else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')                          // is it a number?
   {
      flashSequence (numbers[ch - '0']);
   }
  else if (ch >= 33  &&  ch <=  95)                      // is it punctuation?   
   {

      punctuationTranspose();
      flashSequence (punct[newch]); 

   }
    else if (ch == ' ')                                          // is it a blank space?
   {
     delay(dotDelay * 4);                                    //gap between words
   }
  {    
     Serial.print(ch);
   }
  }
 }

void flashSequence (char* sequence)

{
  int i = 0;
  while  (sequence[i] != NULL)
  {
    flashDotOrDash(sequence[i]);
    i++;
  }
  delay(dotDelay * 3);                                     //gap between letters
}

void flashDotOrDash (char dotOrDash)
{
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  if (dotOrDash == '.')
  {
    delay (dotDelay);
  }
  else                                                           // must be a -
  {
    delay (dotDelay *2);                                  
  }
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(dotDelay);                                         //gap between flashes
}

byte punctuationTranspose()
{
  switch(ch)
  {
  case 1:
  ch=='.';
  newch= 0;
  break; 

  case 2:
  ch==',';
  newch= 1;
  break;

  case 3:
  ch==39;
  newch= 2;
  break;

  case 4:
  ch=='?';
  newch= 3;
  break;

  case 5:
  ch=='(';
  newch= 4;
  break;

  case 6:
  ch==')';
  newch= 5;
  break;

  case 7:
  ch=='!';
  newch= 6;
  break;

  case 8:
  ch==';';  
  newch= 7;
  break;

  case 9:
  ch==':';
  newch= 8;
  break;

  case 10:
  ch=='"';
  newch= 9;
  break;

  case 11:
  ch=='@';
  newch= 10;
  break;

  case 12:
  ch=='-';
  newch= 11;
  break;

  case 13:
  ch=='_';
  newch= 12;
  break;

  case 14:
  ch=='+';
  newch= 13;
  break;

  case 15:
  ch=='$';
  newch= 14;
  break;

  case 16:
  ch=='=';  
  newch= 15;
  break;

  case 17:
  ch=='&';
  newch= 16;
  break;

  return newch;
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. One approach would be to use [Processing](http://processing.org/) with one of [these TTS methods](https://www.google.com/search?q=processing%20text%20to%20speech&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&hl=en&sa=X&as_q=&nfpr=&spell=1&ei=rkMWVOavA-HFigKmuYGIBQ&ved=0CBEQvwU).

Comment: TOMATO, I downloaded "Precessing" and "FreeTTS" and in process of reviewing both. (Processing looks very much like the Arduino API) Appreciate the help. Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated and help cut the learning curve!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in fact it is very possible! TTS is pretty basic (regarding a project like this), and you just have to have a good enough understanding of of the c language to hook up some libraries to your Arduino's output: http://www.devfactor.net/2014/09/22/ship-sinking-and-all-you-have-is-an-arduino-make-your-arduino-blink-s-o-s/